# Transfering RS485 data to server using ethernet

Tags: data, launchpad

I'm extracting data from energy meters like V, I, KW, etc. Now I want to put this data in a dedicated server through Ethernet LAN so that meter user can monitor data from remote place by logging in to particular server address. I'm thinking to buy TIVA C series launch pad from TI.

My question is

1. Will the Tiva C series LP enough for it? or is there any other better option?
2. Refered http://forum.stellarisiti.com/topic/287-enc28j60-booster-pack/ Is it possible with Tiva C series?
3. How to transfer data to particular server? (Very noob in this section)

Comment: Please clarify: you want the micro-controller to be the server, or you want it to upload the data to a remote server? (so the micro-controller will be a client too).

Comment: @ Diego I want upload data to remote server

Answer (score 1):

Any medium-range micro-controller should be fine communicating with the meters. Well, you don't said what is the protocol used at the meters, as RS-485 does not imposes one. Fieldbus does CRC calculations that are more intensive, but it should not be a problem.

As the mentioned products does not have Ethernet PHY embedded then you will use:

Meter - RS485 transceiver - (UART/micro-controller) - Ethernet PHY - Ethernet network

For the RS-485 transceiver you could use a MAX485 for example.

The majority of work is at the TCP/IP stack.

How you would upload your data is a broad topic and has so much solutions. You could develop a protocol of your own, and have optimized bandwidth usage. But this requires a
study at the protocols involved.

Comment: Meter uses modbus protocol. Can you provide links/tutorial to develop protocol on own?

Comment: Google modbus protocol and you get ..... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus and  http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf... not so hard to do ....

Comment: @user2721044 for the meter you will implement Modbus that I think is RTU (binary). That's not so easy depending on your programming skills, there's CRC calculations. About your protocol for upload, it's a long way. You should define structure, messages, etc. Depending on the layer you are that can range from easy to difficult (if you need to write the TCP/IP packet it gets more difficult). If I remember Microchip provided TCP/IP stack implementation for Microchip PIC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this as a one-off, buy a Mikrotik [RouterBoard](http://routerboard.com/) or [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/), run Linux on it and plug in a USB RS485 adapter.  You can get the latter from Ebay for little money.

Routerboards cost little more than a RaspberryPi but come with better processors, other interfaces, e.g. WiFi, a proper case and some have a mains PSU built in.

Some (more expensive) routerboards are rack mount, e.g. RB2011iL-RM and other third parties make DIN rail etc.

If you want to build a product, you can't go wrong with the [ACME Systems Aria G25 Module](http://www.acmesystems.it/aria) as it's only about $20 in unit qty.  It's by far the cheapest way to Linux in a product.
Then you will need a Future Tech (FTDI) FT232 USB UART IC and a Maxim MAX485 RS-485 line driver IC.

Once you have Linux you have a wealth of open source tools and libraries to talk almost any network protocol you can think of.   The most basic way (though not the simplest) is called [SOCAT](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) which will take a serial stream and post it over various IP protocols.